# Update PDF in windows form without losing focus

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm developing a PDF creator using Windows Forms application in Visual Studio Community 2017. I'm using MigraDoc to generate PDFs and they are directly created by a series of data inserted by the user in textboxes.

The page for inserting and displaying the data is the same, because I want a real time update of the PDF document preview. To display the PDF I'm using an axAcroPDF element obtained in the COM section after the installation of Adobe Reader.

In order to update the PDF document I have written a class that simply introduces the new elements (I use a Leave event trigger on textboxes to call the update) and load the new PDF file inside the axAcroPDF element:

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
```

The problem is the fact that each time I insert new data in one of the textboxes and the leave event is triggered it is like the entire form is reloaded and I lose focus on the textbox I was writing on (data inserted remains but the focus gets totally lost and the writing cursor is not preserved). This happens to the other textboxes if I click on another one or if I use tab to move to the next one. Notice that the PDF is correctly updated. Is there any method to avoid this problem and update the PDF section without losing focus on textboxes? Is it also possible doing that on a changetext event listener for those textboxes?

Here is an extract of the code use. The function updateText is called when a changetext event is detected on the textbox:

```
private void updateText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   updateDocument();
   axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
   TextBox s = (TextBox)sender;
   s.Focus();
}
```

Comment: can u share Text_Changed event code

Comment: done, look above to see the code extract